# Image not loading from url via picasso issue

Tags: android, picasso, image-loading

Class loading image in it: i am getting image from url from local server url is "http://localhost/student/api/Images/mazhar.jpg" but image is not displaying url is correct also url is in the variable "Userpic" but its not displaying image in image view dont know why??

```
String Username, Userpic, Useremail, Usermobilenum;
URL PIC;
ImageView UserProfile_iv;
TextView UsernameTV, UseremailTV, UsercellnumberTV;


public Rider() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rider, container, false);

    UserProfile_iv = view.findViewById(R.id.userimage);
    UsernameTV = view.findViewById(R.id.username_tv);
    UseremailTV = view.findViewById(R.id.email_tv);
    UsercellnumberTV = view.findViewById(R.id.usermobile_tv);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        Username = bundle.getString("USERNAME");
        Userpic = bundle.getString("USERIMAGE");
        Useremail = bundle.getString("USEREMAIL");
        Usermobilenum = bundle.getString("USERPHONE");

        if(Utility.isNetworkAvailable(getContext()))
        {Picasso.with(getContext()).load(Userpic).into(UserProfile_iv);}



        UsernameTV.setText(Username);
        UseremailTV.setText(Useremail);
        UsercellnumberTV.setText(Usermobilenum);

    }
```

Comment: because `http://localhost` is your emulator/phone/tablet, not your development computer

Comment: any solution? i have to use local server

Comment: Did you try with IP address?

Comment: any solution? yes: [Set up Android Emulator networking](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking)

Comment: solved it by:Userpic = Userpic.replaceAll("\\blocalhost\\b",Config.HOST);